# How to change PlotLine in highchart from some specific point?

Tags: highcharts

[image]Is it possible to change the plot line from some specific point. One way around is to create two series and plot them on chart them. But we want to change the plot lines from specific point without using two series.

Comment: what do you mean by change it, and what do you mean by 'from some specific point'? An example of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: Its unclear, you mean change plotLine position ?

Comment: I have attached a sample graph, i created the 3 lines using 3 series. but i want to do it by using plotlines and change the plotline on some specific x-axis point as you can see the red boxes on the bottom green line.

Comment: Could you attach how it should look like in the end ?

Comment: #Sebastian please see the above attached screen shot, i want to draw the lower line by using PlotLines not by using 2 series.. i hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: So remove serie and use plotline, am not sure what is wrong.